# python turtle visual progress bar

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

I am making a script and I want to include a visual progress bar before my UI opens. This progress bar would not actually determine progress of any kind, but be on a timer, just for some visual pazzaz. Does anyone have any idea how to make this? i am using TKinter Turtle.

Comment: take a look at https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-progressbar/